# Extremes of: $f(x,y,z)= (x-1)^2y^2(z+1)^2$ with: $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \leq 1$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

I tried using Hessian Matrices, but failed. Mainly because i did not find all the possible points to be maxima, minima or saddles. Any idea for finding the other points?

The points I've found are: $(1,0,0)$ and $(0,0,-1)$

> [image]

Do I have to use Lagrange Multiplier to solve it? Any idea to start?

Comment: This is an ideal set up for Lagrange multipliers, I suggest trying it. The reason why this method fails to produce maxima is because the zeros are all second order - which means zeros of the derivative are also zeros of the original function. The function is also strictly nonnegative. Putting these two pieces of information together, you would never find maxima without Lagrange or a similar method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

The result you found from the first partial derivatives is correct in showing that they are equal to zero for $ \ x = 1 \ , \ y = 0 \ , \ z = -1 \ \ $ (the three planes in the graph at left above).  So the function $ \ f(x,y,z) = (x-1)^2 · y^2 ·(z+1)^2 \ $ has only a single critical point at $ \ (1 \ , \ 0 \ ,  -1) \  . $  Since this point is not on or within the unit ball  $ \ x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \leq 1 \ \ , $ there is no critical *point* satisfying the constraint.

What we do have is a *region* for which the function has the **absolute minimum** value of zero  (since $ \ f(x,y,z) \ $ is non-negative); this is the unit disc, centered on the origin, lying in the plane $ \ y = 0 \ $ (which includes the two points $ \ (1 , 0 , 0 ) \ $ and $ \ ( 0 , 0 , -1) \ $ on the ball's surface).  The situation you have with the Hessian matrix is that *every* entry has factors which equal zero at the values you found for the coordinate variables, so the second partial derivative test is inconclusive.  This critical point is called "degenerate" by some authors:  this often occurs when the point belongs to a line, curve, or even region for which the Hessian is zero.  For such a situation (analogously to the second derivative test in single-variable calculus being inconclusive), we must look at the properties of the function itself (and possibly those of the first derivative function).

The Lagrange system of equations is
$$ 2 · (x-1) · y^2 ·(z+1)^2 \ = \ \lambda · 2x \ \ , \ \ 2 · (x-1)^2 · y ·(z+1)^2 \ = \ \lambda · 2y \ \ , $$ $$ 2 · (x-1)^2 · y^2 ·(z+1) \ = \ \lambda · 2z $$

$$ \Rightarrow \ \ \lambda \ = \ \frac{(x-1) · y^2 ·(z+1)^2}{x} \ = \ \frac{(x-1)^2 · y ·(z+1)^2}{y} \ = \ \frac{(x-1)^2 · y^2 ·(z+1)}{z} $$ $$ \Rightarrow \ \ x · (x-1) \ = \ y^2 \ = \ z · (z+1) \ \ . $$

The first and last parts of the chain equation yield
$$ x^2 - x \ = \  z^2 + z \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ x^2 - z^2 \ = \ x + z \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ (x - z) · (x + z ) \ - \ (x + z) \ = \ 0 $$ $$ \Rightarrow \ \ (x - z - 1) · (x + z ) \ = \ 0 \ \ . $$

[image]

We thus wish to look for extrema on the intersection disks of the unit ball with the planes $ \ z = x - 1 \ $ [in yellow] or $ \ z = -x \ \  $ [in violet]. Because of the form of the function, it is clear that a local maximum of the function would occur at a point as far from $ \ (1 , 0 , -1) \ $ as possible, which makes the latter plane the better candidate to investigate.  We can compare $ \ f(x,y,x-1) = (x-1)^2 · y^2 ·x^2 \ $ with $ \ f(x,y,-x) = (x-1)^2 · y^2 ·(-x+1)^2 \ =  \ (x-1)^4 · y^2 \ $ to observe that
$$ \ x^2 · (x-1)^2 \ \le \ (x-1)^4 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ x^2 \ \le \ x^2 - 2x + 1 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ 2x - 1 \ \le \ 0 \ \ . $$

So for $ \ x < \frac12 \ , $ it will suffice to consider the $ \ z = -x \ $ plane; if we fail to find an evident local maximum solution there, we will need to investigate the situation for the other plane.

In the right-hand graph at the top, the view is downward toward the point $ \ (1,0,-1) \ \ . $ The function is symmetric about the $ \ xz-$ plane ( $  y = 0 $ ) , so the solution we seek will have the form $ \ (x \ , \ \pm y \ , -x ) \ \ . $  We would want a solution as far from that symmetry plane as possible.  We don't actually know (though we may suspect) that the solution points are on the *surface* of the ball, so we will consider concentric spheres centered on the origin $ \ x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \ = \ r^2 \ , \ 0 \le \ r \le 1 \  $ through which we will take "slices" at $ \ y \ne 0 \ , $  and then examine those points for which $ \ z = -x \ \ . $  The graph below presents the geometrical situation.

[image]

For the set of concentric spheres that intersect a $ \ y-$ slice, we have concentric circles $ \ x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \ = \ r^2 \ \Rightarrow \ x^2 + z^2 \ = \ r^2 - y^2 \ . $  The two points for which $ \ z = -x \ $ then satisfy $ \ 2x^2  \ = \ r^2 - y^2 \ \Rightarrow \ x^2 = \frac{r^2 - y^2}{2} \ . $  The function becomes
$$   (x-1)^2 · y^2 ·(z+1)^2 \ \ \rightarrow \ \  (x-1)^2 · (r^2 - 2x^2) ·(-x+1)^2 \ = \  (x-1)^4 · (r^2 - 2x^2) \ \ . $$

Differentiating this expression and setting the derivative equal to zero produces
$$ 4·(x-1)^3 · (r^2 - 2x^2) \ + \ (x-1)^4 · (-4x) \ = \ 4 · (x-1)^3 · (r^2 - 3x^2 + x) \ = \ 0 \ \ .  $$
The solution $ \ x = 1 \ $ is extraneous, since it can only represent the point $ \ (1, 0, 0) \ , $ which is not on the $ \ y-$ slice.  So we must have $ \ 3x^2 - x - r^2 \ = \ 0 \ , $ for which the solutions are
$$ x \ = \ \frac{1 \ \pm \ \sqrt{1 + 12r^2}}{6} \ \ . $$

We want $ \ |x-1| \ $ to be as large as possible.  For the "positive square-root" solutions, this would call for setting $ \ r = 0 \ , $ which would mean the solution point is the origin; this is inconsistent with the conditions discussed. The "negative square-root" solutions will be on the surface of the ball with $ \ r = 1 \ . $  These are

$$ x \ =  -z = \ \frac{1 - \sqrt{13}}{6} \ \approx \ -0.4343 \ \ , \ \ y \ = \ \pm \sqrt{1 - \left(\frac{7 - \sqrt{13}}{9} \right)} \ = \ \pm \frac{ \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{13}}}{3}  \ \approx \ \pm 0.7892 \ \ . $$

So we do in fact find two solution points $ \ \left( \ \frac{1 \ - \ \sqrt{13}}{6} \ , \ \pm \frac{\sqrt{2 \ + \ \sqrt{13}}}{3} \ , \ \frac{\sqrt{13} \ - \ 1}{6} \ \right) \ , $ at which is attained the constrained **maximum value** for the function
$$ (-0.4343 - 1)^2 · (\pm 0.7892)^2 · (0.4343 + 1)^2 \ \approx \ 2.6358 \ . $$ [This is also the value found by WolframAlpha, without any indication of how it is computed.]

Answer (score 0):

Note that if $x^2+y^2+z^2<1$, one can increase the value of $y$ and increase the value of the function so let's assume that $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$. So first of all
$$f(x,y,z)=(x-1)^2(z+1)^2(1-(x^2+z^2))$$
For $x^2+z^2\leqslant1$. Note that if $(x,z)$ make the maximum value where $x\geqslant0$, swapping $x$ with $-x$ will increase the value of $f$ even more so just assume that $x$ is negative so $(x-1)^2\to(-x-1)^2=(x+1)^2$ for positive $x$. Similarly you can deduce that $f$ is maximized for positive $z$. So we want maximum value of $(x+1)^2(z+1)^2(1-(x^2+z^2))$ where $x^2+z^2\leqslant1$ for $x,z\geqslant0$.
Now let $x^2+z^2=c$. By AM-GM inequality :
$$c+2(x+y)+2=(x+1)^2+(z+1)^2\geqslant2(x+1)(z+1)$$
Also by Cauchy Schwarz inequality :
$$2c=2(x^2+z^2)\geqslant(x+z)^2 \iff \sqrt{2c}\geqslant x+z$$
So finally :
$$c+2\sqrt{2c}+2\geqslant c+2(x+y)+2\geqslant2(x+1)(z+1)$$
That also has an equality case where $x=z$. So for a fixed $c$, maximum value of the function will be equal to $f(c)=(\sqrt{\frac{c}{2}}+1)^2(1-c)$ where $0\leqslant c\leqslant1$ and we have to maximize this changing the value of $c$.
Let $2t^2=c$. Then $f(t)=(t+1)^2(1-2t^2)$ for $0\leqslant t\leqslant \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$
By taking the derivative, $f(t)$ will be maximized in one of the following values : $t=0,\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{4}$ where one can check that the maximum happens in the third point which is root of derivative so the maximum value of $f(x,y,z)$ is equal to
$$(\frac{\sqrt{5}+3}{4})^2(\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{4})$$